# Disable link to draft post on published post

Tags: wordpress

Let's say I have post A and post B. I create a link in post A to post B and then I publish post A, but post B is a draft, so visitors will see 404. What I need is to hide link on post A and show it when post B will be published. Any ideas?

Comment: This site is about asking specific questions about code and coding tools. A good question should include context, examples of what you have tried already and a description of the issues you are having. When checking the guidelines, I think you will find this question to be off topic for this website.

Comment: Its logical to only add the link to post B if your are ready to publish it. If the post is not ready you should simply avoid adding the link to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of surprised no-ones written a plugin to do this. For all the bloggers who write multipart articles, I could see the value of something like this.

The easiest way to do this would be with a custom [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), something like this:

```
//[link_if_pub id=123]Part 2 of this post[/link_if_pub]
function link_if_published{$pid, $content) {
    if ( get_post_status ( $pid ) == 'publish' ) { //The target post is published
        $format = '<a href="%s">%s</a>';
        return sprintf($format, get_permalink($pid), $content);
    } else { //Not published or the id doesn't exist
        return $content;
    }
}
add_shortcode('link_if_pub', 'link_if_published);
```